# Display data from all subsites on main site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

Lets say I have a main site labeled projects and a subsite for each project.  I would like to display project data from lists on the subsites on the main site.  The subsites are using a template so all of the form names are the same across the board.

I'd like the main site to pull this data when the page loads.  Ideally this process would be dynamic so that when we add new project subsite, it would automatically include it on the main site.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Can you provide more details on this "project data from lists on the subsites on the main site"?  How many lists will you have and are there any content type attached to these lists?

Comment: We have a custom list on all of our sites on the project status page.  This list is labeled Current Project Status Reports.  I'd like to list the Status reports for each project site on the main site.  This will give us a complete overview of all of our projects in progress.

Comment: I haven't tested this yet but you should be able to use Rest API to get all the lists and filter the lists you want.  Rest API endpoint will be yoursite/_api/Web/webs?$expand=Lists/RootFolder&$select=Lists/RootFolder/ServerRelativeURL

Comment: I have never used the REST API before.  Do you have any resources on it that you find helpful?  I'm a noob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see it there are several ways to accomplish this :
*Custom code to collect the data from the subsides using the rest api
*Using search and some custom search display Template to render the results 
*using workflows on the subsite lists to update a sort of master list on the parent site

However each option will require a developer as it requires coding and testing